# How can we get coordinates of 3D vector with respect to a specific plane?

Tags: plotting, graphics, coordinate-transformation

I have three vectors that are lying down in the 111 plane

```
Module[{origR = {0.5, 0.5, 0}, origB = {0, 0.5, 0.5}, 
  origG = {0.5, 0, 0.5}, red0 = 0.2 {2, -2, 0}, 
  blue0 = 0.2 {-2, 0, 2}, green0 = 0.2 {0, 2, -2}}, 
 Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.7], Gray, EdgeForm[None], 
    Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {-0.5, 0.5, 1}, {0.5, -0.5, 1}}]}, 
   Red, Arrow[{origR, origR + red0}], Blue, 
   Arrow[{origB, origB + blue0}], Green, 
   Arrow[{origG, origG + green0}]}, ImageSize -> 300, 
  FaceGrids -> {Left, Back, Bottom}, FaceGridsStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5],
   Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 1}, {-0.5, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]

How can I get the coordinate of these vectors with respect to the 111 plane, in the new {x',y',0} coordinate? which should look like this

[image]

Comment: The simplest way of achieving this 2D plot is probably to add `ViewPoint->{∞,∞,∞}` as an option to `Graphics3D`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plane is given by $x+y+z=1$, so we can define the $z'$-axis as

```
zp = {1, 1, 1}/Sqrt[3];
```

The red arrow defines the $-x'$ direction:

```
xp = {-1, 1, 0}/Sqrt[2];
```

Finally, the $y'$-axis is defined by the cross product of the other axes,

```
yp = Cross[zp, xp]
(*    {-1/Sqrt[6], -1/Sqrt[6], Sqrt[2/3]}    *)
```

Now we can transform all vectors into the $(x',y',z')$ representation:

```
M = {xp, yp, zp};

origR = {0.5, 0.5, 0};
origB = {0, 0.5, 0.5};
origG = {0.5, 0, 0.5};
red0 = 0.2 {2, -2, 0};
blue0 = 0.2 {-2, 0, 2};
green0 = 0.2 {0, 2, -2};

M . origR
(*    {0., -0.408248, 0.57735}    *)

M . red0
(*    {-0.565685, 0., 0.}    *)
```

meaning that $\text{origR} = 0x'-0.408248y'+0.57735z'$ and $\text{red0} = -0.565685x'+0y'+0z'$, and similarly for the green and blue arrows.

We can now define a transformation from $(x,y,z)$ to planar $(x',y')$ space:

```
T[{x_, y_, z_}] = Most[M . {x, y, z}] // FullSimplify
(*    {(y - x)/Sqrt[2], -(x + y - 2 z)/Sqrt[6]}    *)
```

in terms of which the 2D plot becomes

```
Module[{origR = {0.5, 0.5, 0}, origB = {0, 0.5, 0.5}, 
        origG = {0.5, 0, 0.5}, red0 = 0.2 {2, -2, 0}, 
        blue0 = 0.2 {-2, 0, 2}, green0 = 0.2 {0, 2, -2}}, 
  Graphics[{Red, Arrow[T /@ {origR, origR + red0}],
            Blue, Arrow[T /@ {origB, origB + blue0}],
            Green, Arrow[T /@ {origG, origG + green0}]},
           FrameLabel -> {"x'", "y'"}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Roman gave a perfect transformation to 2D coordinates. However, if you want to keep 3D and only transform the coordinates to the x/y plane, you may proceed as:

We choose arbitrarily a new origin: origR and turn the coordinate system so that the old {1,1,1} axes will point along {0,0,1} in the new axes.

First we set the coordinates, define our points and the new origin

```
{origR = {0.5, 0.5, 0}, origB = {0, 0.5, 0.5}, origG = {0.5, 0, 0.5}, 
  red0 = 0.2 {2, -2, 0}, blue0 = 0.2 {-2, 0, 2}, 
  green0 = 0.2 {0, 2, -2}}; (*set the coordinates*)
orig1 = origR;
pts0 = {origR, origR + red0, origB, origB + blue0, origG, origG + green0};
```

Then we define a transformation that shifts the origin to origR and rotate the coordinate system. With this transfromation we transfrom our points from pts0 to pts1:

```
transform = RotationMatrix[{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}] . (# - orig1) &;

pts1 = {origR, origB, origG, red0, blue0, green0} = transform /@ pts0;
```

With the new points we can draw the graphics:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[pts1[[;; 2]]], Blue, Arrow[pts1[[3 ;; 4]]], 
  Green, Arrow[pts1[[5 ;;]]]}, ImageSize -> 300, 
 FaceGrids -> {Left, Back, Bottom}, FaceGridsStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5], 
 Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]